# Converting code to work in godot with sliders

Tags: animation, python, scripting, godot

I have some [Fragmentarium](https://syntopia.github.io/Fragmentarium/get.html) code that I would like to convert so it will work in Godot anyone have any ideas how I can do this?

The code is below:

```
#include "Progressive2D.frag"

#group Spiral
uniform int StripesNum; slider[1,10,100]
uniform int StripesAng; slider[-180,45,180]
uniform float StripesThinkness; slider[0,0.5,1]
uniform float CenterHole; slider[0,0.125,1]
uniform float OuterHole; slider[0,0.825,1]

const float pi = 3.141592653589793;

vec2 cLog(vec2 z)
{
return vec2(log(length(z)), atan(z.y, z.x));
}

vec3 color(vec2 p)
{
float t = radians(float(StripesAng));
float c = cos(t);
float s = sin(t);
mat2 m = mat2(c, -s, s, c);
vec2 q = m * cLog(p);
return vec3(float
( mod(float(StripesNum) * q.y / (sqrt(2.0) * pi), 1.0) < StripesThinkness
|| length(p) < CenterHole
|| length(p) > OuterHole
));

}
```

Here's the [animation of the code working](https://stillpointx.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/frag_code_sliders.gif) in Fragmentarium
[image: animation of the code working in Fragmentarium]

Here's the [animation of moire patterns](https://stillpointx.files.wordpress.com/2018/07/moire_spirals.gif), I'm trying to recreate this in Godot so I can animate multiple copies of spirals turning at different rates (along with using sliders to adjust variables) to produce different moire patterns.
[image: moire patterns]

Note: 
// Progressive2D.frag This is a utlity / include for the program to set up anti-aliased 2D rendering.
[Progressive2D.frag  code location](https://github.com/Syntopia/Fragmentarium/blob/master/Fragmentarium-Source/Examples/Include/Progressive2D.frag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is apparently a fragment shader code. You can use shaders in godot, since it have its [own shading language](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/tutorials/shading/shading_language.html). It's just a bit different from another shading languages, so I think you can learn it fast.

EDIT:

I achieved a similar result with Godot 3.
In a scene, insert a sprite, then create a new ImageTexture or simple load any image.
After that, create a new ShaderMaterial for Sprite, then create a new Shader for the ShaderMaterial and insert this shader code:

```
shader_type canvas_item;

// group Spiral
uniform float StripesNum = 9; //slider[1,10,100]
uniform float StripesAng = 45; //slider[-180,45,180]
uniform float StripesThinkness = 0.5; //slider[0,0.5,1]
uniform float CenterHole = 0.125; //slider[0,0.125,1]
uniform float OuterHole = 1; //slider[0,0.825,1]

vec2 cLog(vec2 z){
    return vec2(log(length(z)), atan(z.y, z.x));
}

void fragment(){
    float pi = 3.141592653589793;

    vec2 p = UV.xy - vec2(0.5, 0.5); // correct to the center of texture
    float t = radians(StripesAng);
    float c = cos(t);
    float s = sin(t);
    mat2 m = mat2(vec2(c, -s), vec2(s, c));
    vec2 q = m * cLog(p);

    float color = float(mod(StripesNum * q.y / (sqrt(2.0) * pi), 1.0) < StripesThinkness
        || length(p) < CenterHole
        || length(p) > OuterHole
    );

    COLOR = vec4(vec3(color),1);
}
```

The result was the following:
[image: vortex screenshot at godot]

Note the uniform variables: their values can be changed via GDScript with the method [`set_shader_param`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_shadermaterial.html?highlight=ShaderMaterial) from `ShaderMaterial`.